# Why does this REG QUERY command work on Win7, but not WinXP

Tags: windows, batch-file

Comamnd is: `reg query \\cois316\hklm\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework /v EnableIEHosting`

and on Windows 7 this works flawlessly, but on XP I get an error that says either "The network path was not found". The hostname is valid on the network and I can ping from my machine to the hostname.

Script this is being used in:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
echo Main Menu
echo ---------
echo 1) Get Reg Key Status
echo 2) Set Reg Key
echo 3) Exit
echo.

set /p MenuChoice=Choose an option: 

IF %MenuChoice% == 1 (
    set /p Hostname=Enter Hostname: 
    REG QUERY \\%Hostname%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework /v EnableIEHosting
    goto start
)


IF %MenuChoice% == 2 (
    set /p Hostname=Enter Hostname: 
    REG ADD \\%Hostname%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework /v EnableIEHosting /t REG_DWORD /d 

0x00000001
    goto start
)

IF %MenuChoice% == 3 ( 
    goto end
)


IF %MenuChoice% == 4 ( 
    set /p Hostname=Enter Hostname: 
    echo \\%Hostname%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework /v EnableIEHosting
    pause
)



cls

goto start

:END
```

Comment: The following statement contains an `'` which, i think, should not be there.
`REG QUERY '\\%Hostname%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework /v EnableIEHosting'`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I left that in from testing...it still has the error and if I manually enter in the command, I still get the problem.

Comment: Is `REG.EXE` allowed through the firewall in the XP machine?

Answer (score 1):

Okay. the problem is within the following block:

```
IF %MenuChoice% == 1 (
    set /p Hostname=Enter Hostname: 
    REG QUERY \\%Hostname%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework /v EnableIEHosting
    goto start
)
```

Why? As soon the commmand interpreter hits a () block, he automatically resolves all variables contained in this block. That means that the statement `set /p Hostname=Enter Hostname:` will work, but the Hostname variable was already resolved. To prove it, try to add an Echo. e.g. `ECHO Hostname Entered is: %Hostname%`

As soon you queried something and you get back to the :start label, and you query again another server, he's using the previously entered hostname.

To solve this issue, you have to enclose your variables with an exclamation mark. `%Hostname%` -> `!Hostname!` . 
This is only working if you execute the following command initially in your batch file:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

It would work this way:

```
IF %MenuChoice% == 1 (
    set /p Hostname=Enter Hostname: 
    REG QUERY \\!Hostname!\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework /v EnableIEHosting
    goto start
)
```

You have to change this in all other blocks too of course.

I think this would fix your problem on XP.

Comment: I tried this and still got the error, both with and without the single quotes.

Comment: oops... now the single quotes also made it into my answer oO. fixed.

Comment: to do some more debugging, try to print out the req query statement. e.g. `ECHO REG QUERY \\!Hostname!\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework /v EnableIEHosting` . what is the output ?

Comment: I did, it's a "hidden" menu option in the script, but if you select option 4 that's exactly what it does!

Comment: The ECHO looks correct with and without SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAEYDEXPANSION and with either % or !.

Comment: and what happens if you execute the printed statement in a command prompt? i don't have an XP machine any more and therefore, i can't reproduce it

Comment: It looks like it should (save the !Hostname! as the variable didn't get set on the command line). In-script it looks like a perfect command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55784/discussion-between-user1693074-and-acidjunkie).